# DOF computation

Tags: mechanism, hexapod, robotic

I am new to self-learning robotics and while browsing I found quanser hexapod that has 6 degrees of freedom (https://www.quanser.com/products/hexapod/). I used the Grubler's formula in Lynch & Park to verify it, but I am not getting 6.

The number of links that I used is 8 (6 legs + two platforms), and every two legs is connected to the top platform by 4 revolute joints. There are also 2 revolute joints + 1 prismatic joint connecting each leg to the base platform. So together, there are 30 joints.

There may be an incorrect counting that I did. Do you have any idea?

Comment: You're asking people to check your math, but you haven't provided the math you've done. That would be a helpful starting point, and you should probably include that detail in your question.

Answer (score 1):

Though slightly different in the implementation, the device you looked at is a Stewart platform. This [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KkrGUyujKgM) can guide  you through the DoF calculation.

Hope this helps!